# Pulling Values from a JSON Dataset that Match a Keyword

Tags: python, json

Currently working on a school project based on a JSON dataset about a weapon list in a videogame. I've been trying to add functionality where the user can click a button that runs code filtering the dataset down to the forms containing the key-word. Below is the back end code for one of the functions, returning all forms where name = dagger

```py
def wpn_dagger():
    with open('DSweapons.json', encoding='utf-8') as outfile:
        data = json.load(outfile)
        wpn_list = []
    for dict in data:
        if dict in ['name'] == 'dagger':
            wpn_list.append(data)
        print(wpn_list)
        return wpn_list
```

Whilst I do not get any errors when I run the code the only output to the terminal is an empty set of [] brackets. Any help on this issue would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

`if dict in ['name'] == 'dagger'` is wrong syntax for what you want

when written like that `['name']` is a list containing the string `'name'`, so `dict in ['name']` is checking if `dict` is in that list (will be always false) and then we check if the result of that `== 'dagger'`, i.e. the whole thing reads as `if False == 'dagger'`

Try this:

```py
def wpn_dagger():
    with open('DSweapons.json', encoding='utf-8') as outfile:
        data = json.load(outfile)
    wpn_list = []
    for weapon in data:
        if weapon['name'] == 'dagger':
            wpn_list.append(weapon)
    print(wpn_list)
    return wpn_list
```

Answer (score 0):

Indentation in python is very important. Your `for` loop needs to be indented so it operates inside the `with` context manager.

Secondly, `dict` is a keyword in python, so use something different if you need to name a variable.

Finally you can get an object out of your form using `.get('name')` on the dictionary, it's at least easier to read in my opinion.

In summary, something like this (not tested):

```
def wpn_dagger():
    with open('DSweapons.json', encoding='utf-8') as outfile:
        data = json.load(outfile)
        wpn_list = []
        for form in data:
            if form.get('name') == 'dagger':
                wpn_list.append(form)
            print(wpn_list)
    return wpn_list
```

Comment: After running the code the output I received is now multiple rows of single [] brackets. Looks like the for loop seems to be operating properly now but the output is still blank for every item. Thanks for the help thus far though

Comment: Now that it's working, you should be able to use `print` statements to understand each individual line of code and debug from there. Good luck!